# Get all "someValuesFrom" of an object property class with Jena

Tags: jena, ontology

I want to get all the values of "**someValuesFrom**" of each Object Property as a list.

I have this part of an owl file:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#ErgativeFrame">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#hasAgent"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Animal"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Object"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Person"/>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#hasMainAction"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#ErgativeVerb"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#hasOptionalPatient"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Animal"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Beverage"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#BodyPart"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#ClosedLocation"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Clothing"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Food"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Furniture"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#NatureElement"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#NaturePhenomenon"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#OpenLocation"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Person"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Toy"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Transport"/>
                        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Vegetal"/>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:someValuesFrom>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Frame"/>
</owl:Class>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
OntClass ontClass = this.ontModel.getOntClass(NS_OWL + "ErgativeFrame");
List<OntClass> list = ontClass.listEquivalentClasses().toList();

for (OntClass equiv: list) {
    if (equiv.isRestriction()) {
        System.out.println("is restriction");
        System.out.println(equiv.getLocalName());
    }
}
```

The quantity of "is restriction" printed on the screen is equal to the length of properties, but getLocalName is always "null".

What do I have to do?

**EDIT**: I've got the name of property correctly doing some changes in the code (see below).
Now I still can't get the "**someValueFrom**".

```
OntClass ontClass = this.ontModel.getOntClass(NS_OWL + "ErgativeFrame");
List<OntClass> list = ontClass.listEquivalentClasses().toList();

for (OntClass equiv: list) {
    if (equiv.isRestriction()) {
        System.out.println("is restriction");
        System.out.println(equiv.asRestriction().getOnProperty().getLocalName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `getLocalName` is returning `null` is because you are using anonymous classes and properties, i.e. classes and properties without assigned URIs. Since Jena cannot find the URI, it returns `null`.

To illustrate, here is a subset of your ontology with named classes and properties rather than anonymous classes and properties:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#AnimalObjectPerson"/>
</rdf:Description>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Frame"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Object"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Person"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Animal"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#AnimalObjectPerson">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Animal"/>
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Object"/>
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Person"/>
            </owl:unionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#ErgativeFrame">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#hasAgent"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/gumaro/ontologies/2017/11/untitled-ontology-26#Frame"/>
</owl:Class>
```

and here is the code for retrieving the range of the property:

```
        OntClass ontClass = ontModel.getOntClass(NS_OWL + "ErgativeFrame");
        List<OntClass> list = ontClass.listEquivalentClasses().toList();

        for (OntClass equiv: list) {
            if (equiv.isRestriction()) {                    
                OntProperty ontProperty = equiv.asRestriction().getOnProperty();                                        
                OntResource range = ontProperty.getRange();
                List<OntClass> rangeList = range.asClass().listEquivalentClasses().toList();
                for (OntClass rangeEquiv: rangeList) {;
                    for (OntClass rangeUnionClass: rangeEquiv.asUnionClass().listOperands().toList()) {
                        System.out.println("classes in union = " + rangeUnionClass);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided snippet there is ambiguous situation: the restriction `...#hasMainAction` + `...#ErgativeVerb` could be either Data or Object Property Existential Quantification Restriction (for more about this see [owl2 guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/)). 
There are no explicit declarations in the snippet to judge what it is exaclty.

All Restrictions are anonymous resources (class expressions) - that's why they have no uri and local name therefore.

Jena-API (the package `org.apache.jena.ontology`) is only for outdated OWL-1, not OWL-2. 
But there is a jena-based analogue of `org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel` - special for OWL-2: [com.github.owlcs.ontapi.jena.model.OntModel](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/owlcs/ontapi/jena/model/OntModel.java). 
Although it is not directly related to the original question, it might be more useful in this case.

Here is an example:

```
    String fullOwlAsString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
            "<rdf:RDF xmlns=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#\"\n" +
            "     xml:base=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test\"\n" +
            "     xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#\"\n" +
            "     xmlns:rdfs=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#\"\n" +
            "     xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"\n" +
            "     xmlns:owl=\"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\">" +
            "<owl:Ontology rdf:about=\"#\" />" + yourSnippet + "</rdf:RDF>";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fullOwlAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    OntModel ont = OntManagers.createONT().loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(in).asGraphModel();

    ont.ontObjects(OntClass.ObjectSomeValuesFrom.class).map(x -> x.getValue())
            .filter(x -> x.canAs(OntClass.ComponentsCE.class))
            .map(x -> (OntClass.ComponentsCE<? extends OntObject>)x.as(OntClass.ComponentsCE.class))
            .flatMap(x -> x.getList().members())
            .filter(RDFNode::isResource).map(RDFNode::asResource).map(Resource::getLocalName)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And the output:

```
Animal
Beverage
BodyPart
ClosedLocation
Clothing
Food
Furniture
NatureElement
NaturePhenomenon
OpenLocation
Person
Toy
Transport
Vegetal
Animal
Object
Person
```